# Swift 3 - Declared variable giving me 'unresolved identifier error'

Tags: swift

Im trying to use the `securityCode` variable in an if statement but its saying that its an 'unresolved identifier', any idea why?

heres my code:

```
func loginAction (sender: UIButton!){
    guard let url = URL(string: "myurl") else{ return }

    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }
        if let data = data {
            print(data)
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                if let parseJSON = json {
                    let securityCode = parseJSON["security"] as? Bool
                    print("security code bool: \(String(describing: securityCode))")
                }

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

        }

        }.resume()

    if securityCode! == true {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let mainScreen = MainController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        present(mainScreen, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read about scopes in Swift.

`securityCode` was declared inside this `if` statement:

```
if let parseJSON = json {
    let securityCode = parseJSON["security"] as? Bool
    print("security code bool: \(String(describing: securityCode))")
}
```

So, only the code inside the scope of this `if` statement will be aware of `securityCode`.

If you want the code after this `if` statement to be aware of `securityCode` you need to make its declaration outside of that scope, and this can be achieved like this:

```
var securityCode: Bool?
if let parseJSON = json {
    securityCode = parseJSON["security"] as? Bool
    print("security code bool: \(String(describing: securityCode))")
}
```

Comment: Don't declare `securityCode` as implicitly unwrapped. Either make it optional or make it non-optional and give it an initial value.

Comment: @Moe Abdul-Hameed Thanks! Works fine now

Answer (score 0):

```
if securityCode! == true {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let mainScreen = MainController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    present(mainScreen, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

This is out of scope.

To make it work, you have to embed the function into the same scope. For example,

```
if let parseJSON = json {
     let securityCode = parseJSON["security"] as? Bool
     print("security code bool: \(String(describing: securityCode))")

    if let securityCode = securityCode{
        if securityCode == true {
           let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
           let mainScreen = MainController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
           self.present(mainScreen, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Or declare the variable outside session.

Comment: Do not force-unwrap `securityCode`. The app will crash if it is `nil`.